# Codeigniter undefined variable site in views

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, undefined

Views:

I got the error  when i run the program : undefined variable site in views
This is the following code:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $site ?>/CI_timeline/index">HOME</a></li>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo $site ?>/CI_timeline/aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo $site ?>/CI_timeline/services">SERVICES</a></li>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo $site ?>/CI_timeline/photogallery">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo $site ?>/CI_timeline/promogallery">PROMO GALLERY</a></li>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo $site ?>/CI_timeline/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Moreover i got the error  in views undefined variable image in the following code:

```
<img src="<?php echo $base?>/<?php echo $image?>/fb.png" alt="" title="" />
```

Also  i got the error like undefined variable css, base

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url() ?>assets/css/style.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url() ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"  type="text/css" />
```

Please provide solution  for this issue.

Comment: try this go to application > config > autoload.php and do this $autoload['helper'] = array('url'); in line 86

Comment: Make sure you pass those variables to your template from your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Timelinestudio extends CI_Controller{

    var $data;
     function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); 
 //session_start();
 $this->load->model('timeline_model');
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->data = array(
        'site' => $this->config->item('site_url'),
              'base' => $this->config->item('base_url'),
              'css' => $this->config->item('css'),
              'js' => $this->config->item('js'),
     'img'=>$this->config->item('img'),
     'image'=>$this->config->item('image')
               );

               // $data = $this->data;
                //print_r($data); die();

    }

 public function index()
 {
  $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
  $data = $this->data;
  //print_r($data); die();
  $this->load->model('timeline_model');
    $data['slideimg']=$this->timeline_model->get_slideimg();

  $this->load->view('index',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because **`$site` is not contain any value**.

this should be

```
<?php echo $site ?>
```

this

```
<?php echo base_url() ?>
```

**And do this Configuration as well** ***(This will help to use `base_url` function)***

1. In `config/config.php`

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = '';
   ```
2. In `config/autoload.php`

   ```
   $autoload['helper'] = array('url')
   ```

Comment: but i  did not recover from the error  undefined variable site

Comment: i didnt get your idea

Comment: i got the  error   undefined variable base and image in the following code:<img  src="<?php echo $base?>/<?php echo $image?>/img4.png" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px; width:114px" />

Comment: undefined variable : site_url() in views                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $site_url() ?>/CI_timeline/aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>   and i got the error:  function name must be a string

Comment: i told you to use `base_url ()` insted of these `site_url()` and `$site`

Comment: bt i got the same error undefined variable base_url

Comment: Check the **And do this Configuration as well** on my answer

Comment: @user  happy to help :)

Comment: $this->data = array(
'site' => $this->config->item('site_url'),
'base' => $this->config->item('base_url'),
'css' => $this->config->item('css'),
'js' => $this->config->item('js'),
'image' => $this->config->item('image')
        );  when i echo  this  i did  not gt the path

Comment: if you want path use `echo $base_url()`